# LibreOffice Online - multiple users with access_header

Tags: multi-tenant, libreoffice

I'm trying to integrate LibreOffice Online with a cmis repository and for that I need to use the "access_header" for my requests.

When I try to use with multiple users only the first user appear in all instances.

Example:

access_header:xxxx - user1

> http*//libreoffice.docker.localhost/loleaflet/dist/loleaflet.html?WOPISrc=http*//docker.localhost/alfresco/service/wopi/files/0503eed5-6a0e-4267-9c1f-a27806bf7b4a&access_header=xxx"

access_header:yyy - user2

> http*//libreoffice.docker.localhost/loleaflet/dist/loleaflet.html?WOPISrc=http*//docker.localhost/alfresco/service/wopi/files/0503eed5-6a0e-4267-9c1f-a27806bf7b4a&access_header=yyy

The request from cmis is returning the right user, but In both instances the users "logged" are "user1".

I tried with access_token and works well (I need access_header because I need a basic authentication).

Anyone can help me?

Thanks